# Getting TypeError: slice() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'result1' and 'result2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

im currently making an email slicer project for practice in python and so far i came up with this line of code:

```
`from tkinter import *

import strip as strip

root=Tk()
root.geometry('600x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Email slicer")

Email = StringVar()



Label(root , text='Enter the Email address here:', font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0,y=20)
Entry(root, width=35, textvariable = Email).place(x=300,y=26)

def slice(result1 , result2):

    email = Email

    result1 = email[:email.index('@')]
    result2 = email[email.index('@')+1:]

    Label(root, textvariable=result1, font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=300, y=110)
    Label(root, textvariable=result2, font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=300, y=150)


Label(root, text="Your username is:", font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0, y=110)
Label(root, text='Your domain is:', font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0, y=150)

Button(root, font='arial 10 bold', text= 'Submit', bg='Cyan', padx=2, pady=2, width= 20, command=slice).place(x=200,y=60)



root.mainloop()`
```

In this project i created gui witch receives the email address and separates the user name and the domain and then showing them separately. The problem is when i submit the email to be slice i receive the next error message:

```
 TypeError: slice() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'result1' and 'result2'
```

It would help me a lot if someone knows why is that happening and how it can be fixed

Thanks

Comment: As the error says, your `slice` function takes two arguments, but you aren't supplying them when the function is called.

Comment: What are you expecting to be passed as `result1` and `result2`? The button's `command=slice` argument will be called like `slice()`, since there's nowhere to specify the arguments. Maybe you should use a lambda instead? And what are you expecting the values of `result1` and `result2` to be if they're not defined or in scope at that point?

Comment: @Carcigenicate `result1` and `result2` aren't even in scope or defined at that point, right?

Comment: @RandomDavis Oops, somehow I got the scope confused. Well, if `result1` and `result2` are defined in the function, it looks like those parameters should simply be removed.

Comment: Good point - @Gnugget, do `(result1 , result2)` even need to be arguments of that function, considering those values are never read in the function before being re-assigned new values? If you just had it as `def slice():` then this issue would go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.geometry('600x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Email slicer")

Email = StringVar()
result1 = StringVar()
result2 = StringVar()

Label(root , text='Enter the Email address here:', font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0,y=20)
Entry(root, width=35, textvariable = Email).place(x=300,y=26)

def slice():

    email = Email.get()

    user = email[:email.index('@')]
    domain = email[email.index('@')+1:]

    result1.set(user)
    result2.set(domain)



Label(root, text="Your username is:", font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0, y=110)
Label(root, text='Your domain is:', font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=0, y=150)

Button(root, font='arial 10 bold', text= 'Submit', bg='Cyan', padx=2, pady=2, width= 20, command=slice).place(x=200,y=60)
Label(root, textvariable=result1, font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=300, y=110)
Label(root, textvariable=result2, font='arial 15 bold ').place(x=300, y=150)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem that's great. It will be alot more helpful if you added some explanation as to what was your mistake and how you actually solved it, rather than simply posting code